# Backbone model save blocking the UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

What I want to do is show a 'Saving' message (using jQuery's slideDown()) before saving the backbone model and hide it after the response is recieved from the server (jQuery slideUp()). However, for some reason, even though when debugging everything seems to be working as it should, the jquery slideDown is not triggered until after the response is recieved from the server. Here's my code:

```
   saveSystemConfiguration: function (result) {
        /// <summary>
        /// Saves the system configuration. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns type="Object">The promise.</returns>

        var self = this;
        Global.eventAggregator.trigger('loading:start', $('#savingPopupMsg').text());

        var promise = this.model.save({}, {
            success: function (model) {
                model.set('isNew', false);
                self.dirty = false;
                result.success = true;
                Global.eventAggregator.trigger('loading:end', $('#savingPopupMsg').text());
                self.isSaving = false;
            },
            error: function (model, error) {
                self.isSaving = false;
                result.success = false;
                Global.eventAggregator.trigger('loading:end', $('#savingPopupMsg').text());
                self.displayError();
            },
            async: false
        });

        return promise;
    }
```

The loading:start and loading:end events are handled by the loadingView which triggers the slideDown() and slideUp().

```
    var loadingView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#loadingPopupView'),

    initialize: function () {
        /// <summary>
        /// Sets up listeners on the event aggregator.
        /// </summary>

        _.bindAll(this, 'showView', 'hideView');
        Global.eventAggregator.on('loading:start', this.showView);
        Global.eventAggregator.on('loading:end', this.hideView);
        this.minDisplayTime = 1000;
    },

    showView: function (msg) {
        /// <summary>Shows the loading view.</summary>
        /// <param name="msg" type="Object">The message to display while loading.</param>

        this.$('#loadingReason').text(msg);
        this.$el.slideDown('fast');

        this.minDisplayTimeReached = new $.Deferred();

        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            self.minDisplayTimeReached.resolve();
        }, this.minDisplayTime);
    },

    hideView: function () {
        /// <summary>Hides the loading view.</summary>

        var self = this;

        if (!this.minDisplayTimeReached) {
            return;
        }

        this.minDisplayTimeReached.done(function() {
            self.$el.slideUp('fast');
        });
    }
});

return loadingView;
});
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone delegates its HTTP requests to jQuery and you explicitly pass [`async: false`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to the request:

> **async** (default: true)
>   By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need
>   synchronous requests, set this option to false.

Remove this option for a non blocking call.